# RethinkDB: how to append to an array in a nested structure

Tags: rethinkdb

I am trying to append to an array in a nested field, which I have to find based on runtime information.

Here's an example:

```
r.db("test")
  .table("test")
  .insert({ "stock": [{ "bin":"abc", "entries":[{ "state":1 }] }] })
```

The idea is that the document contains a "stock" key, which is an array of multiple "storage bins". Each bin has a name and a number of entries. I need to be able to append to entries in one of the bins, atomically, without affecting other bins.

I tried this approach:

```
r.db("test")
 .table("test")
 .update(function(item) {
    return {"stock": item("stock")
     .filter({ "bin": "abc" })
     .append({ "state":42 })
    }
 })
```

…but that does not append at the right level, and I am not certain if it will preserve existing bins with names other than "abc".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When updating an element of an array, you should use `changeAt` with an index, or `map` over the array instead of using `filter`.

Here is what that query might look like:

```
r.table("test")
 .update(function(item){
   return {"stock": item("stock").map(function(stock){
     r.branch(stock.hasFields({"bin": "abc"})
       stock.merge({"entries": stock("entries").append({"state": 42})}),
       stock)})}})
```

Alternatively, if you stored your entries in an object instead of an array, like this:

```
{ "stock": {"abc": {"entries":[{ "state":1 }] }} }
```

The update query might look like this:

```
r.table("test")
 .filter(r.row.hasFields({"stock": {"abc": true}}))
 .update({"stock": {"abc": r.row("stock")("abc").append({"state": 42})}})
```

Comment: If you're using object entries like the bottom half of answer above and are using nodejs driver, since you can't user r.row in nested queries, you can do something like `
.update({
  "stock": {
    "abc": r.table("test").get(...).append({ "state": 42 })
  }
}, { nonAtomic: true })`